# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/event/EventPublisher

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm trying to run my script, but, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/event/EventPublisher

at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventPublisher
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 24 more
```

I have imported the latest versions of this cucumber jars as external libraries to my project in Intellij IDEA:

- cucumber-core-5.0.0-rc1.jar
- cucumber-java-5.0.0-rc1.jar
- cucumber-junit-5.0.0-rc1.jar
- cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
- gherkin-8.11.jar
- junit-4.13-rc-1.jar
- mockito-all-2.0.2-beta.jar

And I have imported also latest Selenium Webdriver Jar files for Java.

And this is my script:

```
package TestRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="Features",glue={"StepDefinition"})
public class Runner
{
}
```

Any help to fix this issue is much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Please understand that a screen shot of some "folder" with jars in it ... doesn't tell us anything about your setup. In other words: please describe *how* exactly you "installed" these jars, and how you are running your project.

Comment: Your dependencies are not correct. You're missing `cucumber-plugin`. You should not manually manage them. Use maven and only import your direct dependencies.